# Reporting suite for making data available to customers

Tags: web-apps, reporting

We have a requirement to make basic spend reports available to our customers. The data for these reports would come from our in-house SQL Server. I'm looking at these as an alternative to developing an ASP.NET ReportViewer control for SSRS (which we use locally).

Requirements are:

- Accessible from a link on our web site.
- Must be able to enter parameters in the  link (i.e., so customer X can go to report X etc).
- Happy to pass through to a third party hosted solution.
- Happy to pay a license cost but would prefer it if it was not *per* *user*.

Users would already be authenticated on our website (i.e., the link is not readily available to the public).

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Report Platform](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/report) Can meet your requirements.

- Can be linked to from your website (you can host the report server and link to it)
- Report URL can take parameters specifying report and category and you can use that to send specific customers to specific reports
- License cost is per user, but there are flexible flat licensing options through the sales team

The report platform and more are available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: If you have a cURL example, you could help out on [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52157/rest-api-for-creating-charts-from-json-data)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/) a try, it does what you want, as it lets you [call reports directly by their URL address](http://dbxtra.com/documentation/#topic/report-web-service/Legacy%20%20Report%20Web%20Service%20-%20version%208/report_web_service-l8.htm), even letting you pass parameters to your query directly from the URL; also, you can pass your log in credentials and, if you don't want to deal with security, you can make the report publicly accessible, and access it by calling its URL directly.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.

Comment: Does DBextra allow for exporting of reports into Excel? I'm now weighing up options against an Azure VM running SSRS - which does do this.

Comment: Yes, it does, you can export a designed report, or just a grid of the data into Excel.