# REST API for creating charts from JSON data

Tags: api, charts, json, rest

I am in search of an REST API to convert JSON data to charts and then get back as image. There were many available of this kind, but all are specific language-based client libraries or SDKs. However I need a REST API with curl examples and support to achieve this. Could someone who used it before suggest me one like it? Google Charts API shows implementation with HTML and JavaScript, but I need to implement in a new programming language, thus curl examples could help me to convert more easily. Please suggest me one.Not necessary to be completely free,atleast some trial period to experiment with
And I am just asking for an API service with detailed explanation of necessary parameters and headers.An example API call in curl and successful response.
I doesn't mean the language only has curl interface ,but how could it would be much simpler and clear with a curl example.I found one such API service plotly.But it uses basic authentication.Looking for an alternative with oauth.

Comment: " I need to implement in a new programming language" why would that matter, if you use a REST API? Just curious. And, to clarify, you are developing a client-side solution and looking for a server-side API, correct?

Comment: Yes sir,actually I am in need to implement this for a cloud based integration using the language that the service provider support.What I mean is I am in need of rest API service that has edpoints and examples of queries in curl too besides providing html,JavaScript implementation codes as in Google charts API .Sorry if I am wrong,I am not aware whether there is such service by Google.could you guide me with one such API provider.

Comment: I wish to integrate a cloud service with another app that requires to program in that company's own programming language.So I am struggling to make those API requests in JavaScript or python.Instead if it's a curl example I could figure out the query process even more easier.

Comment: Lolx ! "`the company's own programming language`" - how many times have I heard those dread words ()? I don't mean laugh; I created an in-house language last year, but ***why*** do we do it? I hope you find your CURL example. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you,I have to learn a lot.:)pee..not mature enough like you people.Any way thanks for your icebreaker.

Comment: So, your in-house language has a CURL interface, but no direct HTTP GET?

Comment: Btw, if you are looking for a free solution, use the [tag:gratis] tag; otherwise, please state a budget. The more info that you give us, the more that we can help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83157/discussion-between-mariappan-gameo-and-mawg).